# Crash When Selecting Video For UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePicker that is being used to pull in videos on my new application. I have noticed that according to Crashlytics I am receiving a number of crashes where the below movieURL is nil when inserting into the movie array.

I tested it before release with a number of videos and all seems to be fine. As mentioned however since release I have had a number of crashes.

The error report in question is:

```
Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

The actual code the receives the video is as follows:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:( UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *movieURL = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];

    CompileViewController *compileViewController = [[CompileViewController alloc] init];
    compileViewController.movieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [compileViewController.movieArray insertObject:movieURL atIndex:0];

     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:compileViewController animated:NO];


}
```

Here is the code for selecting the video with the picker.

```
-(IBAction)loadVideo {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

}

I was wondering what could be causing the user to provide a nil result for "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" and how I could go about resolving this issue. I have looked at trying to capture an error but I don't think the method has one. I think I could check for the nil value before entering it into the array but I would like to know why the result is coming back as nil in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any trend in the devices/system version it occurs on?

Comment: All IOS 7 and a pretty even split between the 4,4s and 5 range of IPhones

Comment: What about 5s? Keep in mind that the 5s has a 64 bit processor.

Comment: Yep the 5s as well. Pretty even split accross them all. I was wondering if it had something to do with disk space?

Comment: The app is on the app store and it is about 5-10 percent of the users who are receiving the error. The rest seem to be ok.

Comment: I suggest you do some testing. A 5%-10% error rate is pretty likely to show up at least once during testing.

Comment: I am going to try with a 10+ minute video and see if I can get a result we regards to space.

Comment: Just tried a 10 minute video without a problem. Not sure what else to test.

Comment: Test as in test on multiple devices, in multiple scenarios, with multiple users. Is any one user getting the error more than once?

Comment: Unfortunately I am developing on my own and only have access to the 4s and an IPad. I'm kinda going off the crash reporting. Looking at the reports it does seem to be happening to a few users more than once.

Comment: Try contacting those users and see if they're willing to help you sort out the issue. Put the code in a try-catch block and try to know more about the issue. If that's not possible, consider using your free technical support incident. Sounds more and more like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you properly limiting the media selection choices for your UIImagePickerController? It is possible, depending on configuration, to not get what you are expecting.

Your code is assuming that the value you are retrieving from the dictionary will exist and be valid. Your runtime crashes are telling you that's not true.

Could you post the setup code where you configure your UIImagePickerController? In particular, have you done things like verify availability (using isSourceTypeAvailable: and  availableMediaTypesForSourceType:), etc?

If you're leaving open any possible path for user to get out of you UIImagePickerController without recording a movie, there will be no file and hence no URL pointing to it (url will be nil).

Edit --

Based on your comments, I don't see any obvious problems. But there may be issues with configuration, movie format and/or user-granted permissions for access. I'd act on these two warnings from documentation:

> Always call the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method of the
>   UIImagePickerController class and respect its return value. Never
>   assume that a device has a photo library. Even if the device has a
>   library, this method could still return NO if the library is currently
>   unavailable.

and

> [media type]: However, before setting this property, check which media types are
>   available by calling the availableMediaTypesForSourceType: class
>   method.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code that is used to select the video content above. It was a mistake to not check to see if the value did exist.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will add some additional error checking to the code.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a more definite answer. Like you, code runs fine for me on my device as-is. Could not get it to fail by doing any odd stuff, revoking access permission in settings, etc. So obviously a config out there we don't know about, or as duci9y suggested a bug in some version of the OS.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I am a bit surprised myself. I have added a check to see if the result is nil before adding it to the array. If nothing is present I show the user an alert message.